# ISNULL() within ISNULL()

Tags: t-sql

Which way is better?

```
ISNULL(@firstvalue,ISNULL(@secondvalue,1))
```

or

```
ISNULL(ISNULL(@firstvalue,@secondvalue),1)
```

in T-SQL?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
SELECT COALESCE(@firstvalue,@secondvalue,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ISNULL(@firstvalue,ISNULL(@secondvalue,1)
```

is optimal in case if the `@firstvalue` is not `NULL`,
`COALESCE()` is a better approach.